# PHP Error: Function registration failed - duplicate name - curl_init

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am using Oracle RightNow which uses the Zend framework. I have the code below in a model.

```
function getTicketAvailability($id){
        \load_curl();
         $url = "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/".$id."/ticket_classes/?token=XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $body = \curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $json = \json_decode($body,true);
        return $json["ticket_classes"][0]["on_sale_status"];
    }
```

If I call it once in a page, all is well. If I have to call it twice, I get the following:

```
Function registration failed - duplicate name - curl_init
```

I also get the same for curl_copy_handle, curl_version, curl_setopt, curl_setopt_array etc

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does the `load_curl` function do? It sounds like the Curl extension is being loaded twice.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems load_curl initializes those functions, so check first if they are existing, if not load it.

```
if (!function_exists("\curl_init"))
{
    \load_curl();
}
```